# Threading and Tasks issues

Tags: java, multithreading, task

I am currently learning Java. I am creating a project that gets info from users, then create sql files. During that (lengthy) process, I show a panel showing the progress, using Tasks and Threads. However, I found out that if I wait 10 seconds at the beginning, the code performs as expected, but if there is no sleeping, the program exits right away. Any information is greatly appreciated!

```
    package GUI;

    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;

    public class GUIMainPanel implements ActionListener
    {
        private static JFrame frame;

    public GUIMainPanel()
    {
            // Code that creates a panel, getting information from the user
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GUIMainPanel gui = new GUIMainPanel();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getActionCommand() == "Continue")
        {
            Runnable r1 = new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    // Progress Monitor frame
                    ProgressMonitor pbd = new ProgressMonitor();
                }
            };

            Runnable r2 = new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    // Code that creates files and changes the progress
                }
            };

            Thread thread1 = new Thread(r1);
            Thread thread2 = new Thread(r2);

            thread1.start();
            thread2.start();
        }
    }
}

    package GUI;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import Queries.CreateListsQueries;

import java.beans.*;

public class ProgressMonitor implements PropertyChangeListener
{
    private static JProgressBar progressBar; // Progress bar showing the progress of the query creation process
    private static JLabel creatingQueriesLabel; // Label showing information about the current state of the query
                                                    // creation process
    private Task task; // Task used to update the progress bar and label based on the current state of the query
                         // creation process
    private static JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public ProgressMonitor()
    {
        // Code creating the Progress Monitor Panel and displaying it

        // Instances of javax.swing.SwingWorker are not reusuable, so
        // we create new instances as needed.
        task = new Task();
        task.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
        task.execute();
    }

    class Task extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>
    {
        /*
         * Main task. Executed in background thread.
         */
        @Override
        public Void doInBackground()
        {
            int progress = 0;
            double tempProgress = 0;
            String currentQueryText = "Test";

            try
            {
                // Infamous 10 seconds wait here
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ignore)
            {
                ignore.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Initialize progress property.
            setProgress(0);

            while (progress < 100)
            {
                progress = GUIMainPanel.getProgress();
                setProgress(progress);
            }

            return null;
        }

        /*
         * Executed in event dispatching thread
         */
        @Override
        public void done()
        {
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();

            frame.setCursor(null); // turn off the wait cursor

            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Invoked when task's progress property changes.
     */
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt)
    {
        if ("progress".equals(evt.getPropertyName()))
        {
            int progress = (Integer) evt.getNewValue();
            progressBar.setValue(progress);
        }
        if ("currentQueryText".equals(evt.getPropertyName()))
        {
            String text = (String) evt.getNewValue();
            creatingQueriesLabel.setText(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you have `System.exit(0)` right in the middle of your code.  Is that being called?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It is called (or should be called) when the Task is complete, so when progress is >= 100.

Comment: Honestly your code is complicated enough that I think we're going to need an example that compiles and demonstrates the problem.  [See here.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  I don't think anyone will find it just by reading the code.

Comment: `e.getActionCommand() == "Continue"` is wrong; this should really be `"Continue".equals(e.getActionCommand())`.

Comment: Removed parts of code to make it clearer. The problem is that the when the Task is executed, it finishes immediately (the done() method is called right away). However, if I try to debug the doInBackground() method, I can't reproduce the issue as everything runs smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found it :).

Once I created more than one task (see below), everything went smoothly. Thank you to everyone for your help :).

```
while (GUIMainPanel.getProgress() < 100)
{
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ignore)
    {
        ignore.printStackTrace();
    }

    task = new Task();
    task.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
    task.execute();
}
```